# How do I stop automatic calendar reminders from a disabled Google Apps domain that I can't sign into anymore?

Tags: reminder

I cancelled my Google Apps domain, yet I still get the monthly email reminders of recurring monthly events from the calendar that I had set up.  When I try to log into Google Apps, I can't, because the domain has been disabled.

How do I stop these emails?

Answer (score 1):

I think you will have to contact the [support](http://www.google.com/support/calendar/bin/request.py?contact_type=contact_policy) to have this solved from the inside.

But you could also create a special filter that covers something unique from all these notifications that you're getting and trash them. I would guess that inside the body of the e-mail there is an e-mail with your old domain, since this was a Google Apps domain.